# Git(Github) : How to sync two separate directories and pick the latest changes

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

**Background**

So, I'm working on two Android projects, with a shared module. I don't know how I'd keep this module in sync with the latest changes across the two projects.

**Assume:**

```
projectA : github/android/projectA/shared_module
projectB : github/android/projectB/shared_module
```

So whenever I change something at `shared_module` in Project A, I have to manually import again the module into Project B.

Anyway I can achieve this with Git? Or any other way to keep this sync, even if not through Git?

Comment: [This](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/git-project-dependencies) _may_ help.

Answer (score 1):

You can publish this module as your own library.

may this tutorial help you:

1. [Building-your-own-Android-library](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Building-your-own-Android-library)
2. official [android-library](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library) doc.
3. [publish-an-android-library-by-jitpack](https://medium.com/@ome450901/publish-an-android-library-by-jitpack-a0342684cbd0)(Good Tutorial).